# convert string date to datetime format in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataFrame, with a column of Date:

```
    ID  Amount   raw-Date   ZIP transaction-ID  Date    flag
749     145552  $100.00 1/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  1/15/2018   1.0
1307    145552  $100.00 3/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  3/15/2018   1.0
1672    145552  $100.00 2/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2/15/2018   1.0
3508    145552  $100.00 4/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  4/15/2018   1.0
4144    145552  $250.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  4/24/2018   1.0
4145    145552  $100.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  4/24/2018   1.0
4787    145552  $100.00 5/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  5/15/2018   1.0
8350    145552  $212.44 12/21/2018  27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  12/21/2018  1.0
```

When I sort them by the Date column, i.e., using `data.sort_values('Date')`, I get:

```
ID  Amount   raw-Date   ZIP transaction-ID  Date    flag
749     145552  $100.00 1/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  1/15/2018   1.0
8350    145552  $212.44 12/21/2018  27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  12/21/2018  1.0
1672    145552  $100.00 2/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2/15/2018   1.0
1307    145552  $100.00 3/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  3/15/2018   1.0
3508    145552  $100.00 4/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  4/15/2018   1.0
4144    145552  $250.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  4/24/2018   1.0
4145    145552  $100.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  4/24/2018   1.0
4787    145552  $100.00 5/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  5/15/2018   1.0
```

in which apparently it sorts dates as a string. I tried `pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` and again got same sorted result:

```
    ID  Amount  raw-Date    ZIP Appeal ID   Date    flag 
749     145552  $100.00 1/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-01-15  1.0
8350    145552  $212.44 12/21/2018  27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-12-21  1.0
1672    145552  $100.00 2/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-02-15  1.0
1307    145552  $100.00 3/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-03-15  1.0
3508    145552  $100.00 4/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-04-15  1.0
4144    145552  $250.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  2018-04-24  1.0
4145    145552  $100.00 4/24/2018   27614-7901  1234-O8910-B32  2018-04-24  1.0
4787    145552  $100.00 5/15/2018   27614-7901  1342-P0192-F43  2018-05-15  1.0
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: `data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])` didn't work? You have to reassign back to data['Date'].  Check `data.info()` to see that the dtype of Date column is after pd.to_datetime.

Comment: Looks like a case of duplicated column names here.

Comment: @QuangHoang, well, for posting the question I edited the column name to keep the confidentiality of data, and it resulted in two columns of same name. In what I have they have same name. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you asking about sorting or convert to datetime? Did you reassign the sorted data: `df = df.sort_values('Date')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I asking about sorting date, which are sorted as string, not as datetime.

Comment: @QuangHoang I assigned the sorted datafram to new datafram: `tmp = data[data['ID'] == id_].sort_values('Date')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has duplicated column name `Date`, which is discouraged. In this case: `df['Date']` would give a dataframe with two columns, and `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` would fail.

That said, you can do an `apply`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

After that, `df.Date.dtypes` would give:

```
Date    datetime64[ns]
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: `data.Date.dtypes` returns `dtype('<M8[ns]')`. 
To get this columns I have `data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['raw-Date'])`

Comment: `'<M8[ns]'` is an alias for `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: Also, pass `errors='coerce'` to `pd.to_datetime` would help.